# Not able to set max width for a table in HTML webview in Cocoa

Tags: html, css, objective-c, cocoa, html-table

I am implementing a Print functionality where I want to have a table with a dynamic column height. For this, I am creating webview and HTML string using DOMElement. On debugging the HTML created, I found that below HTML string is created.

```
<body><p></p><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0"><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead><tr><style><td word-wrap="break-word" max-width="100px"></td></style><td style="border-top:1px silver solid; border-bottom:1px silver solid; border-right:1px silver solid;border-left:1px silver solid;">22502  </td><td style="border-top:1px silver solid; border-bottom:1px silver solid; border-right:1px silver solid;border-left:1px silver solid;">1234567890123456789012345678901123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678902345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</td>
</tr><tr><style><td word-wrap="break-word" max-width="100px"></td></style><td style="border-top:1px silver solid; border-bottom:1px silver solid; border-right:1px silver solid;border-left:1px silver solid;">28760    </td><td style="border-top:1px silver solid; border-bottom:1px silver solid; border-right:1px silver solid;border-left:1px silver solid;">123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012354645691231231231123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123451234567890</td></tr></table></body>
```

The issue here I have found is that instead of `td{word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 400px;}` the format is `<td word-wrap="break-word" max-width="100px">`

Could some one let me know how to create `td{word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 400px;}` using DOMElement.

Following is what is currently being used:

```
    [arrangedObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *str, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        DOMElement *tr = [theDOMDocument createElement:@"tr"];
        DOMElement *style = [theDOMDocument createElement:@"style"];
        [tr appendChild:style];
        DOMElement *outerTD = [theDOMDocument createElement:@"td"];
        [outerTD setAttribute:@"word-wrap" value:@"break-word"];
        [outerTD setAttribute:@"max-width" value:@"100px"];
        [style appendChild:outerTD];
        [tableColumns enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSTableColumn *column, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            DOMElement *td;
            td = [theDOMDocument createElement:@"td"];
            [tr appendChild:td];
            [td setAttribute:@"style" value:@"border-top:1px silver solid; border-bottom:1px silver solid; border-right:1px silver solid;border-left:1px silver solid;"];
            newText = [theDOMDocument createTextNode:str];
            [td appendChild:newText];
        }];
    }];
```

Comment: Dynamically add the style tag into your html page.Style tag must have the td{word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 400px;}.thats is simple

Comment: @iyyappan: Thank You for the response. I did similar to what you have said and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Fix:
The fix was to add the css string using `setInnerHTML` api available for `DOMElement`. I was doing a `appendChild` which was creating a wrong format.

```
DOMElement *trElement = [theDOMDocument createElement:@"tr"];

NSString *cssTDString = @"td {word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 400px;}";
DOMElement *style = [theDOMDocument createElement:@"style"];
[style setInnerHTML:cssTdElement];
[trElement appendChild:style];
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically add the style tag into your html page.Style tag must have the td{word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 400px;}.

**Note**: If you are doing anything dynamic add the script tag or style tag with required script and css.